# ¿Cómo actualizar una tabla con una sentencia que haga un ciclo en aumento en SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Trato de crear una sentencia SQL que me permita actualizar la columna `Numero` en aumento; es decir que parta de 1 y vaya sumando de 1 en 1.

Al ejecutar el código la tabla si actualiza los valores, pero los pone en 1 a todos.

Si lo vuelvo a ejecutar, actualiza el valor que ya hay y lo aumenta más 1.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como pueden ver, es una tabla que registra ventas, las cuales, necesitan una serie y un número.

Lo que necesito es crear la sentencia SQL que me permita actualizar la columna `Numero` en aumento por cada registro, según la columna `Serie`.

Que quede algo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estas son las sentencias que he usado hasta ahora.

````
UPDATE DBO.DocumentoVenta
SET Numero = Numero + 1
WHERE Serie = 1

--Seleccionar
Select * From dbo.DocumentoVenta
where serie = 1

--Test(error)
Select Format(Numero, '0000000'+ cast(Numero))
as Numero
From dbo.DocumentoVenta

--Update (Error)
DECLARE @serie int
set @serie = 1
WHILE @serie <= 10
begin
    update DocumentoVenta
    set Numero = Numero + 1
    where Serie = 1

    if((Select Numero From dbo.DocumentoVenta) = null)
        break
    else
        continue
end ```
````

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! cuando decis error.. que error te dio?

Answer (score 1):

Usar ciclos para actualizar tablas fila por fila es generalmente una mala idea en SQL. En vez de eso, calculamos todo en una sola instrucción diciendole al motor de la base de datos que es lo que queremos que haga y dejando que el motor decida como hacer los bucles de forma interna de manera eficiente.

En este caso, podemos utilizar la función ROW_NUMBER() para asignar números consecutivos que pueden ser reiniciados en cada grupo. Así no hace falta que definamos un bucle dentro de otro.

```
WITH cteDocumentoVenta AS(
    SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY Serie ORDER BY IdDocumentoVenta) AS NumeroFila
    FROM dbo.DocumentoVenta
    --WHERE condiciones necesarias
)
UPDATE cteDocumentoVenta
SET Numero = NumeroFila;
```

Como anotación final, para comparar contra valores nulos, utilizamos `IS NULL` o `IS NOT NULL`  porque si utilizamos el signo de igual, siempre regresará 'desconocido' que no es verdadero ni falso.